# I am trying to print an active sheet as a PDF, is it also possible to print page 1 and 2 separately? i have this so far

Tags: vba, excel, export, file-conversion, export-to-pdf

I am trying to print an active sheet as a PDF, is it also possible to print page 1 and 2 separately? i have this so far. i want the name of the export to use the values from cells B1 I1 and J1

Sub PDFActiveSheet()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim strFile As String
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set ws = ActiveSheet

'enter name and select folder for file
' start in current workbook folder
strFile = Replace(Replace(ws.Name, " ", ""), ".", "_") _
        & "_" _
        & Range("B1"&"I1"&"J1") _
        & ".pdf"
strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile

myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

If myFile <> "False" Then
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

    MsgBox "PDF file has been created."
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `From` and `To` parameters of the `ExportAsFixedFormat` function:

```
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=myFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False, _
    From:=1, _
    To:=1
```

and the same again with page 2